# Restrict the rows retrieved from database for the relationship between the domain classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm, relationship, grails-domain-class

I have two domain classes:

```
class Entity {
    static hasMany = [
            titles: Title
    ]
}

class Title {
    Boolean isActive

    static belongsTo = [entity:Entity]  

    static mapping = {
        isActive type: 'yes_no'
    }
}
```

Now when I am calling Entity.get(0) I would like to take from the database the Entity with id=0, but only with active Titles (where isActive = true). Is it possible in grails? I've tried to add where clause in static mapping of Title domain class:

```
static mapping = {
    isActive type: 'yes_no'
    where 'isActive = Y'
}
```

or

```
static mapping = {
    isActive type: 'yes_no'
    where 'isActive = true'
}
```

but it doesn't work. I am using Grails in version 2.2.1

Could You help me? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use `criteria` to do that:

```
Entity.createCriteria().get {
  eq('id', 0)
  projections {
    titles {
      eq('isActive', true)
    }
  }

}
```

I don't think it's possible to set a default where to be applied in all your database calls to that Domain Class.

You can also wrap your logic in a service:

```
class EntityService {
  def get(Long id) {
    return Entity.createCriteria().get {
      eq('id', id)
      projections {
        titles {
          eq('isActive', true)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Long time no see. One sort of 6K, I will be glad to make that mark for you :). BTW You can make it simpler using `idEq`.

Comment: @dmahapatro Hey! I'm busy trying ExtJs4. Thanks for complementing with the `idEq`, cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me. I am still getting all titles.

Comment: You have Title associated to the Entity with `isActive` `false`? You can also enable sql output to see the generated query, using logSql=true in the datasource config.

Comment: Point for `logSql=true`. It is very useful in that case. I have in my database Entity with 3 titles (2 active and one no active). And now I've found that `def e=Entitiy.createCriteria().get{(...)}` generetes sql that is returning two rows, because I have two active titles. But then when I am trying to print this titles by call: `print e.titles` it is creating new sql without where clause `isActive=true` and it prints all titles.